# Interrupt and Dispatcher

Tags: c, linux, unix, operating-system

Are interrupt and dispatcher different process or they are simple routines which may be called in between a process ?

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you mean by "interrupt" and "dispatcher" processes?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel arranges to set up different interrupt handlers for different interrupts.  The hardware largely deals with the calling of the appropriate handler once the setup is done.  The dispatcher is separate from the interrupt handlers.  They are all part of the kernel, though, and are not really a separate process.  However, different systems can come up with different answers for these questions.  What applies on MacOS X (with its Mach kernel) is different from Linux, which is different from Solaris or AIX.

The full discussion, therefore, takes a lot of time, and you'd do better with the appropriate book(s).